# Go Loop over elements and insert into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I have an issue that I cannot figure out how to solve it. I have a Go endpoint to read the content of a txt file and return its content. This file is structured as follow:

```
usertest1,usertest1
usertest2,usertest2
```

The first step is to read the lines and split at the comma. This works just fine as I get back the result as:

```
[
{
   name: userttest1
   surname: usertest1
},
{
   name: userttest1
   surname: usertest1
}
]
```

this logic work just fine with the following block of code

```
    var dataSlice = make([]Element, 0)
    lines := strings.Split(string(fileBytes), "\n")
    var txt *models.TextParser
    if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&txt); err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
    for _, line := range lines {

        keyVal := strings.Split(line, ",")
        dataSlice = append(dataSlice, Element{Name: keyVal[0], Surname: keyVal[1]})
ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, dataSlice)

}
```

My element is presented as follow:

```
type Element struct {
    Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Surname string `json:"surname" bson:"surname"`
}
```

But now I wanted to test this loop and insert each element in a mongo database. So I started with my Model

Model:

```
type TextParser struct {
    Name  string    `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Surname  string    `json:"surname" bson:"surname"`
    CreateAt  time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
}

type DBTxt struct {
    Id        primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name  string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Surname  string             `json:"surname" bson:"surname"`
    CreateAt  time.Time          `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time          `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
}
```

This is my text service:

```
type TxtService interface {
    CreateTxt(*models.TextParser) (*models.DBTxt, error)
}
```

This is the text service implementation:

```
type TxtServiceImpl struct {
    txtCollection *mongo.Collection
    ctx           context.Context
}

func NewTextService(txtCollection *mongo.Collection, ctx context.Context) TxtService {
    return &TxtServiceImpl{txtCollection, ctx}
}

func (t TxtServiceImpl) CreateTxt(text *models.TextParser) (*models.DBTxt, error) {
    text.CreateAt = time.Now()
    text.UpdatedAt = text.CreateAt
    res, err := t.txtCollection.InsertOne(t.ctx, text)

    var newTxt *models.DBTxt
    query := bson.M{"_id": res.InsertedID}
    if err = t.txtCollection.FindOne(t.ctx, query).Decode(&newTxt); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return newTxt, nil
}
```

Now that I had all the required code to actually add values to mongo db. I updated my controller to perform the database insert. My logic (totally wrong actually), is while the loop is running and updating my element array, I could use that loop to insert the values in the mongo db. So I did the following:

```
var dataSlice = make([]Element, 0)
    lines := strings.Split(string(fileBytes), "\n")
    var txt *models.TextParser
    if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&txt); err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
    for _, line := range lines {

        keyVal := strings.Split(line, ",")
        dataSlice = append(dataSlice, Element{Name: keyVal[0], Surname: keyVal[1]})
        newTXT, err := tc.txtService.CreateTxt(dataSlice)
        if err != nil {
            if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "title already exists") {
                ctx.JSON(http.StatusConflict, gin.H{"status": "fail", "message": err.Error()})
                return
            }

            ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadGateway, gin.H{"status": "fail", "message": err.Error()})
            return
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"status": "success", "data": newTXT})

        }
    }
```

When I try to run the project, I get the following error:

```
#13 15.09 controllers/parser.controller.go:77:42: cannot use dataSlice (variable of type []Element) as *models.TextParser value in argument to tc.txtService.CreateTxt
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go install -v ./...]: exit code: 1
```

If anyone can help understand my error I would be grateful.

Comment: In the line `newTXT, err := tc.txtService.CreateTxt(dataSlice)` you call `CreateTxt`. This is defined as `func (t TxtServiceImpl) CreateTxt(text *models.TextParser) (*models.DBTxt, error)`, so it expects a pointer to `models.TextParser` as an argument. But `var dataSlice = make([]Element, 0)` defines `dataSlice` as a slice of `Element`. So the types do not match, hence the error.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Thank you so much for your answer. I also realised my mistake as not declaring tc as a pointer to TxtServiceImpl. I corrected that and tried to convert my data slice to an interface `var newDataSlice = make([]interface{}, len(dataSlice))` but the error was the same. So I tried to convert the data slice to an interface. but I get this error `cannot use newDataSlice (variable of type []interface{}) as *models.TextParser value in argument to tc.txtService.CreateTxt
`

Comment: For me it seems you want to map your `Element` to  `TextParser` which has all fields of Element plus additionally `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt`. How such a conversion could look like, see in my answer (with a simplified working example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to insert each document separately with a call to `CreateTxt`.

The document to be inserted is of type `TextParser` (perhaps the name `ParsedText` would be a better fit, since it is only a data object and not a parser).

After you have a slice of `Element`, you want to convert it to `ParsedText` and probably add the current time in the `created_at` and `updated_at` database fields.

This could be done for each `el` of type `Element` something like this:

```
    doc := ParsedText{
        el.Name,
        el.Surname,
        time.Now(),
        time.Now(),
    }
```

Maybe it is a good idea to extract the parsing functionality to a separate function. This could be called `parse` for example and return a slice of element.

```
func parse() ([]Element, error)
```

A working, simplified, stand-alone example might then look something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Element struct {
    Name    string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Surname string `json:"surname" bson:"surname"`
}

type ParsedText struct {
    Name      string    `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Surname   string    `json:"surname" bson:"surname"`
    CreateAt  time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
}

type DBTxt struct {
    Id        primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name      string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Surname   string             `json:"surname" bson:"surname"`
    CreateAt  time.Time          `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time          `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
}

func CreateTxt(ctx context.Context, collection *mongo.Collection, text *ParsedText) (*DBTxt, error) {
    res, err := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), text)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var newTxt *DBTxt
    query := bson.M{"_id": res.InsertedID}
    if err = collection.FindOne(ctx, query).Decode(&newTxt); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return newTxt, nil
}

func parse() ([]Element, error) {
    return []Element{
        {Name: "C.J.", Surname: "Cherryh"},
        {Name: "George", Surname: "Orwell"},
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    collection := client.Database("db").Collection("elements")

    dataSlice, err := parse()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, el := range dataSlice {
        doc := ParsedText{
            el.Name,
            el.Surname,
            time.Now(),
            time.Now(),
        }
        dbTxt, err := CreateTxt(ctx, collection, &doc)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("result: %v\n", dbTxt)
    }
}
```

`parse` obviously delivers only some mock data, but this is only intended to demonstrate the conversion part.

**Additional Remarks**

Noteworthy is that MongoDB also offers `insertMany()`. With it you can insert a whole slice at once.

If you want to go this route, your parameter for `CreateTxt` could then be `dataSlice []interface{}` for example. The `dataSlice` would be created with type `[]interface{}`. You would add several `ParsedText` objects, similar to the code shown above.

The insert code would look something like this:

```
    res, err := t.txtCollection.InsertMany(t.ctx, dataSlice)
```

Since you seem to be interested in the IDs, you can then retrieve them with `res.InsertedIDs`.

Comment: @StephenSchlecht thank you so much for your help and answer. While I fully understand the issue where it is I might be missing something here and I cannot figure out what(maybe just need some rest and read once again the docs) or maybe is my docker-compose missing something. But even with you implementation I am getting this error `cannot use &doc (value of type *ParsedText) as *models.TextParser value in argument to tc.txtService.CreateTxt`

Comment: The idea was to *rename* `TextParser` to `ParsedText`, for the reason given in the answer, so that you should not have both `TextParser` and `ParsedText` in the code. So remove either `TextParser` or `ParsedText` and adjust the places where the type names are used.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I missed to clarify this. One of the tries was to use your code and renamed the TextParser to ParsedText, but the error was exactly the same. This is because the function when I am calling the `CreateText` is of type `func (tc *TxtController) ConsumeFile(ctx *gin.Context)` so when I use this `dbTxt, err := tc.txtService.CreateTxt(&doc)` (I cannot pass directly `CreateText` I get the error mentioned before

Comment: The types of the arguments to a function must match the types of the parameters passed when the function is called. The error message `cannot use &doc (value of type *ParsedText) as *models.TextParser value in argument to tc.txtService.CreateTxt` clearly indicates that there are two different types `models.TextParser` and `ParsedText` in the code and thus the problem occurs. You can e.g. remove `ParsedText`, make `doc` of type `models.TextParser` and pass it via `&doc`  to `CreateTxt`, as it expects a pointer.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question a bit. A minimal, reproducible example would allow people here to better help, see more here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)